# Any ideas to removing a not allowed sign flashing on screen?

Tags: 20.04

A white circle with a stroke inside a grey box(just like "not allowed"sign) keeps appearing on my ubuntu 20.04 and thus freezing it for like a second or two and goes away and then comes back again(two seconds or three tops intervals)......I tried to remove it by disabling all the audio keyboard shortcuts but the sign wont go away...what seems to be the problem?

Comment: i have not the faintest idea what you are asking here.

Comment: What is "this"?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? It looks like the system requires to install updates.

Comment: I kinda new here and I don't have that much privileges to upload photos

Comment: You can upload a photo somewhere and post a link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18-aZCpypbKgdzV_d9_l8Pmk_zwo8h8z9/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: open a terminal and type `sudo showkey`.  Is there any output when this is happening and you are not touching any input devices?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this: [not allowed sign flashing on screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317262/not-allowed-sign-flashing-on-screen) and see if it helps you.
Your question is a possible duplicate. Im pretty sure it will not though because it tells you to disable a few shortcuts, which im pretty sure you already did, but atleast read it.