# Cannot type double quote symbol

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I cannot type the double quote symbol (").

[image: Here is a screenshot of what shows up when I press the double quote key.]

It makes no difference which keyboard layout I use. It is always the double quote symbol that cannot be typed.

I am using ubuntu 20.04 but I recently updated from Ubuntu 16.04 where the problem with the double quote also persisted.
But the symptoms were a little different. If needed, I can describe how my double quote problem expressed itself when I was using Ubuntu 16.04.

I can't remember since when I have this double quote problem.
But I remember vaguely that some years ago I tried to do something with the keyboard configuration or something similar. It may have to do something with that but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I guess the double-quotation key is set to a global shortcut which nothing to do with typing software. You can search `.bashrc` or `.profile` related comment with `Shift+2` I assume you are on ISO layout. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317262/not-allowed-sign-flashing-on-screen) perhaps helps when it is your case.

Comment: I mean [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340265/keyboard-stops-working-and-a-no-symbol-is-on-the-screen) might be your case.

Comment: I can't believe it, after so many years... @Sadaharu Wakisaka Thanks for the [first link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317262/not-allowed-sign-flashing-on-screen). I now also remember that I put assigned a key to the "play/pause" key of my keyboard. It was shift+". I always thought that it was something mor complicated what I did. I searched several times for this issue. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad that you solved this case!