# I'm encountering a ban/prohibited symbol in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

When I see a **prohibited or ban** symbol on **Ubuntu 20.04** my keyboard becomes unresponsive everywhere except in the Ubuntu search box when I attempt to type.

*For example:*
When I want to type in Notepad or Google, a **'ban'** symbol keeps flashing, and I can't type anything. However, when I use Ubuntu's **'Show Applications' search box,** I can type without any problems.
(You can see ban/prohibited symbol in below screenshot)

Despite attempting the solutions provided on Ubuntu support, I haven't been able to resolve this issue. I have tried a solution available on Ubuntu support but it does not help. I have checked the keyboard driver as well.How to fix this issue?

I have tried these solutions:

[solution1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340265/keyboard-stops-working-and-a-no-symbol-is-on-the-screen)

[solution2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317262/not-allowed-sign-flashing-on-the-screen)

[image]

Comment: I have rebooted device many times and changed screenshot. Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: When your question has enough information to be answerable, then somebody will answer it.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: I have only one laptop and which has keyboard issue. I have tried my best to ask question. Please let me know what I am missing. I have done enough research as well. I have tried to be specific

Comment: Borrow a friend's USB keyboard and test it on your machine. If your laptop keyboard is faulty, there is nothing Ubuntu can do beyind remapping a couple keys. Ubuntu is not designed to operate on faulty hardware.

Comment: What make /model of laptop is it? Some laptops have a function key to disable the keyboard.

Comment: @user535733 I have mentioned in my post that  '_when I use Ubuntu's '**Show Applications' search box**, I can type without any problems_ '. I have borrowed keyboard but its behave same way my laptop behaving. There is an issue in kernal but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Will Its lenovo ideapad 330. Problem is not with keyboard its linux kernal which giving me an error. If I disable keyboard its temporary solution

Comment: Please edit your question to add the new information. Avoid commenting on your own question. Comments are intended to help you improve your question until it is answerable.